# Spring4 How to use Service in Validator

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
public class BoardValidator implements Validator {
    @Autowired
    BoardService boardService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return BoardVO.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {        
        boardService.getAllList();

        //TODO add

    }

}
```

create Validator like this

Can use boardService in controller package

but in validator boardService is Null

how to use Service @Autowired in Validator class?

Comment: You should include an import for `Validator` in your source example. Otherwise people won't exactly know which Validator is meant. There is for example `javax.validation.Validator` and `org.springframework.validation.Validator`.

Comment: you have to first annotate you validator (@Component)

Comment: @SpaceTrucker i use import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

Comment: @hasnae add (@Component) but still Null

Comment: I tend to use the `@Configurable` annotation and add `<annotation-driven />` and `<context:load-time-weaver/>` to the application context configuration.

Comment: @MyBrainHurts `context:component-scan base-package="com.testproject.validator" />` / `<context:annotation-config /> `/ `<context:load-time-weaver/>` in `application-context` and use `Configurable` annotaion but still NULL

Comment: You need to annotate the validator as @hasnae said (`@Component`), and the validator object itself must be managed (created) by Spring, so you can't just do `new BoardValidator()`. Autowire the validator object to the BoardService class and then use it (`@Autowire BoardValidator yourBoardValidator`).

Comment: Start by using *constructor* injection, which will immediately show you where this class is being instantiated so you can make sure it's handled as a Spring bean.

Comment: @mdrg thanks it work